# writing environment variable and reading it from the same process

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variable from a console application by executing it from my windows application. I invoke console application and send the value of environment variable as parameter to it, then set the thread to wait for 10 seconds to proceed with next execution. 
In the next step i try to load a new .exe which reads the  value set to the environment variable.
The exe will not read the new value and continue to refer the value set earlier.

Once the solution of application is closed and open then it reads the new value i.e reload the vshost.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx

Answer (score 1):

betting you set up the variable only for the current process. You should try this [overload of the Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) :

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("YourVar", "YourValue", 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

[Edit] Re-Reading your question, you said in the title "same process", and in the question "new exe". In term of Env varialble, spanning a new process implies a new process scope for env variables. They won't share env variables with process scope just because it's the same executable. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do at a higher level.

[Edit2] not sure to understand why it fails... But you can specify env variable when spawning process using a [ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx)

Basically, it can be (not tested) :

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName="yourExe"
};
psi.EnvironmentVariables.Add("YourVariable","YourValue");
var process = Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Hi steve reframing my question below I have a windows application where i set the envrionment variable through code. Then I invoke a third party application through the same winodws application, which needs to read the value of the environment variable. Though it is able to read the value, it always gets the previous value and not the latest updated value from the windows application.

If i kill the application along with vshost and then read the environment variable, i am able to get the newly set value..

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: In my windows application I call the exe 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\New Folder\\Env\\SettingEnv\\bin\\Debug\\SettingEnv.exe", strFilesPath);

In this exe I have Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("YourVar", "YourValue", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) 

Next i proceed to load a third part exe which should read the value from the environment variable set

Comment: My Third Party exe reads environment variable set at machine level

Comment: We dont call the third party exe directly we send input parameters to it and get back output parameters. So I have a Execute method where i send the parameters and call the method exposed by third party exe. Is it possible to put a method call in a new process? Because wrting a environment variable in one process and reading it from same will not work.

Comment: how do you call the 3rd party executable ?

Comment: a method is exposed by that third party which takes the file name to open as input

Comment: how do you call the 3rd party executable's method ?

Comment: As said a method is exposed by the 3rd party executable.I add dll of that executable in my application and instantiate object of it and call the method exposed

Comment: in this case, the process is your own executable (the second, spawned by the first). So the env variable of your own executable's process should be applied, isn't it ?